# Can you recommend a good php Gantt charting development?

Tags: php

I would like to add a simple Gantt chart to my development, was wondering if you could recommend any that seem good to you. I don’t need anything really flash (I’m not trying to reproduce MS Project) just need to plot a number of projects over a 24/7 timeframe. Would appreciate your comments

Answer (score 1):

[JpGraph](http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/features.php) rocks. And it has a Gantt chart module.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is a good control named jSGantt purely written in javascript ,CSS,HTML and can be integrated with any language There is good tutorial based on ASP.net languge here [CodeGlobe](http://codeglobe.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-gantt-chart-in-aspnet.html)

Or you can look at jsGantt website there is a tutorial based on you preferred language PHP

Answer (score 0):

[fusionchart](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/) (free version) can be alternative as it is using flash so it looks more interactive